# Bezier curve proportional editing with aligned handle type

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bezier-curves, proportional-editing

Maybe someone knows why it behaves like that. Why it affects dots not evenly. Dots on the left side is more affected then on the right. I would appreciate your help.[Link on Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/174xDWUIuJViwAWnpcQoEFU1OyMAQvWL2/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: that's normal if you are using proportional editing. pls read https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html or edit your question why/what you think is not "normal"

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @Chris, Why it affects dots not evenly? Dots on the left side is more affected then on the right.

Comment: pls provide blend file, so we can check it out. thx

Comment: @Chris it's easy to reproduce, you need to create a straight segment parallel to $x$ axis, with one middle cut. Set Spline type to bezier, and handle types to aligned. I think because aligned handle types are, well... aligned, you can't arbitrarily move two points at once. So in proportional editing a priority may be given based on e.g. point index - which is not symmetrical…

Comment: this is what happens when there are two curves, and one of them is reversed: https://i.imgur.com/ieUtrPS.gif

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, yes I thought about priority too because in automatic handle type it works the way I expected it should work. I just decided to q experienced people maybe they know... I am kind of new in program.

Comment: So... nobody don`t know exactly(